# react-three-fiber change model function in canvas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, react-state, react-three-fiber

I want to change the model function in the canvas. I have two different Models(functions in js files) (Model1 and Model2). Both have the functionality to outline the mesh if they are hovered. The code looks like this:

```
import Model1 from './Model1'
import Model2 from './Model2'

export default function Scene1() {
  const [hovered, onHover] = useState(null)
  const selected = hovered ? [hovered] : undefined
  return (
    <div className="App" style={{ position: "relative", width: 450, height: 300 }}>
      <Canvas classname="scene" camera={{ zoom: 10 }}>
        <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
          <color attach="background" args={["#383838"]} />
          <ambientLight intensity={0.1} />
          <spotLight intensity={0.4} angle={0.5} penumbra={1} position={[10, 15, 10]} castShadow />
          <Model1 onHover={onHover} />
          <EffectComposer multisampling={8} autoClear={false}>
            <Outline blur selection={selected} visibleEdgeColor="#0e3000" hiddenEdgeColor="#0e3000" edgeStrength={30} edgeThickness={10} />
          </EffectComposer>
          <OrbitControls />
        </Suspense>
      </Canvas>
      <button onClick={shoot}>change</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Now I want to change the

```
<Model1 onHover={onHover} />
```

to

```
 <Model2 onHover={onHover} />
```

so I have Model2 loaded in my scene and not Model1 anymore.
If I do it manually in vs code it works. But how can I do it for example with a click on a button?
I've tried it with useState but it dont seem to work with function. Can someone help me with an example?

Comment: You can try ternary operator to render different Model depend on some variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very simple with useStates. I added following in the function to get it to work:

```
const [currentModel, changeModel] = useState("Model1")

var models = {
  Model1: <Model1 onHover={onHover} />
  Model2: <Model2 onHover={onHover} />
}

function change(){
changeModel("Model2")
}
```

And in the canvas I changed

```
<Model1 onHover={onHover} />
```

to

```
{models[currentModel]}
```

And for the button

```
<button onClick = {change} >
      change model
</button>
```